# Need help passing survey responses from HTML form to MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, http-post

I'm a bit stumped here...

I've got a web page that displays a list of survey questions that are stored in a db table, and I'm trying to gather ratings responses on each question (strongly disagree -> strongly agree) and pass the values back to another table in my db.

Here's a snippet of the form code:

```
<form action="submitAnswers.php" name="subAns" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Survey Questions</legend>
            <input type="hidden" name="survey_id" value="<?php echo ($survey_id); ?>">
            <table width=90% border=0 cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'?>

            <tr bgcolor=#D0D0D0>

                <th>Question</th>
                <th>Strongly Disagree</th>
                <th>Somewhat Disagree</th>
                <th>Neither Disagree nor Agree</th>
                <th>Somewhat Agree</th>
                <th>Strongly Agree</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
            <?php
                while ($row  =  mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
                {
                    echo "<td bgcolor='#E8E8E8'><font size='-1'>$row[quest_order]) $row[quest_text]</font></td>";

                    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
                    {
                    //echo "<input type='hidden' name='qID' value='$quest_id'>";

                    echo "<td bgcolor='#E8E8E8'><input type='radio' name='$row[quest_id]' value='$i'></td>";
                    }           

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>      

            <br>            
            </table><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit Survey"></fieldset>
    </form>
```

And here's the PHP in the 'submitAnswers.php' file:

```
$survey_id=$_POST['survey_id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO survey_responses (survey_id) 
            VALUES ('$survey_id')";

    $res = send_sql($sql, $link, $db);  


    foreach($_POST['quest_id'] as $id=>$value)
    {   

        $sql = "INSERT INTO survey_answers (response_id, quest_id, response_value) 
            VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), $id, '$value')";

        $res = send_sql($sql, $link, $db) or die("Cannot add survey");

    }
```

My insert statement into the 'survey_responses' table works just fine, but I don't know how to correct my radio buttons used to obtain the response score for each question.  The values are being passed with POST (I confirmed this by looking at `print_r($_POST);`, which returned, for example:

> Array ( [survey_id] => 4 [6] => 0 [5] => 1 [4] => 2 [3] => 3 [2] => 4
>   [1] => 3 [submitAnswers] => Submit Survey )

but clearly I'm going about this wrong, as I'm not able to successfully iterate through and insert the question id# and response value for each one.  I'm sure this is relatively simple, but I'm still new to programming and have been going over this for hours with little to no luck.

Just hoping someone can help me fix this, and hopefully in the process better explain, or point me to a good resource covering how to handle dynamically sized forms that are retrieving database records and passing various amounts of information back to the db.

Thanks!

Comment: i think u got nothing in $_POST['quest_id']

Comment: the quest_id values are the [6], [5], [4], in the array above.  quest_id = 6, response value (via radio button selection) = 0.  I don't know how to isolate those 6 questions and responses so I can insert the values into my table.  $_POST is sending them, but I just think I'm handling them incorrectly...

Comment: Please sanitize your database inputs as well so you don't get hacked :)
http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sql-injection-attack-examples-and-preventions-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO survey_answers (response_id, quest_id, response_value) 
        VALUES ('".LAST_INSERT_ID()."', '".$id."', '."$value."')";
```

instead

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO survey_answers (response_id, quest_id, response_value) 
        VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), $id, '$value')";
```

Comment: If you provide code like this, make sure that you explain that the code needs protection from SQL injections: http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sql-injection-attack-examples-and-preventions-in-php.html

Comment: No luck...replacing my code with that actually prevented my first INSERT from working.  I think the syntax is OK, I'm just not handling the values properly...

Comment: @span thanks -- I'm aware of the injection risks, and plan on addressing that later, but am just trying to get the main functionality working first...

Comment: Glad to hear you know about them, security should never come later though. Then it is easily forgotten, better to do it right from the start :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've got this licked, though there may be a better solution.  In my form, I changed the radio buttons to read as follows:

```
echo "<td bgcolor='#E8E8E8'><input type='radio' name='quest".$row[quest_id]."' value='$i'></td>";
```

The only change was adding 'quest' as a prefix to the ID# in the name attribute.  In my PHP file:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name=>$value)
{
    if (strpos($name, "quest") !== FALSE)
    {
    $qID = substr($name, 5);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO survey_answers (response_id, quest_id, response_value) 
        VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$qID', '$value')";

    $res = send_sql($sql, $link, $db) or die("Cannot add survey");
    }
}
```

I'm checking the post values for those with the 'quest' prefix, then extracting the id# via `substr`.

If there's a better way I'm all ears...